# Calculating gains and losses of overlapping number regions

Tags: bash, perl, sorting, addition

The numbers in the second and third column specify a range. What I want is (if the number in the first column is the same) to calculate overlapping regions, and calculate how many in a range are gained or lost as determined by the number on the right(+1 = one gained, -1 = one lost). 
For example if I have

```
1   0   300  +2
1   100 200  -1
2   100 200  -1
```

This means I actually have

```
1   0   100   +2
1   100 200   +1
1   200 300   +2
2   100 200   -1
```

because `1   100 200` overlaps with `1   0   300` creating `0   100   +2`, `100 200   +1` and `200 300   +2` but `2   100 200` has no overlaps and simply prints out `2   100 200   -1`

Sample input

```
1   0   5000    +1
1   100 400 -1
1   300 500 +2
1   1000    1200    +3
1   1000    1100    -2
1   0   50  -1
```

expected result

```
1  50   100 +1
1  300  400 +1
1  400  500 +3
1  1000 1100    -1
1  1100 1200    +2
1  1200 5000    +1
```

Some sort of pseudocode for how to accomplish this would be nice

But languages which would work for me are bash, perl, awk or sed

Comment: Have you written anything?

Comment: @codeforester I haven't I can't think of how I could manipulate the numbers to do that

Comment: Why is 300 - 400 "+1"? I'm getting +2.

Comment: @choroba: I agree. It's within only the first three ranges: 0 .. 5000 (+1), 100 .. 400 (-1), and 300 .. 500 (+2). The total is +2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each distinct value of the first column, create a list of all start and end points of the ranges that it's divided into.

Sort those points

For each line of data, add the delta value to all ranges between the limits

(You may combine multiple ranges if they are adjacent and end up with the same value)

Print the result

Comment: What do you mean exactly by delta value

Comment: @Bob: I mean your column four. It always helps if you name your data fields in your question so that we have terms to use that we can both understand.

Answer (score 1):

Store the data in a hash table. The topmost key is the id (the 1<sup>st</sup> column). Second level keys are the "breaks", i.e. the borders of the regions where the gain changes. The values are how much the gain changes.

When printing the output, just keep a running gain and add the stored value to it; print if the result isn't zero. Note that the output is different to your expected one, but I got mine when trying to solve the problem by pen and paper, too.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my %table;

while (<>) {
    my ($id, $from, $to, $gain) = split;
    $table{$id}{$from} += $gain;
    $table{$id}{$to} -= $gain;
}

for my $id (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %table) {
    my $previous;
    my $gain = 0;
    for my $break (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %{ $table{$id} }) {
        if (defined $previous) {
            $gain += $table{$id}{$previous};
            say join "\t", $id, $previous, $break, $gain
                if $gain;
        }
        $previous = $break;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1       50      100     1
1       300     400     2
1       400     500     3
1       500     1000    1
1       1000    1100    2
1       1100    1200    4
1       1200    5000    1
```